# What is the search rank where people stop searching on Google?

Tags: google-search, ranking, search-results, users

What is the stopping point on Google SERPs where most people stop searching?

Does it vary by different keywords? For example, if I was searching for "Orlando hotels", I would instinctively look at the popular and well known brand names first. Then, I would see which has the cheaper price and then finally, which is the better deal.

Is there a specific number or page for the stopping point?

Comment: That is impossible for us to know. In fact, I am sure it varies from individual to individual or even as the SERP results fluctuate/change over time.

Comment: "I would instinctively look at the popular and well known brand names first. Then, I would see which has the cheaper price and then finally, which is the better deal." - But your own method of searching does not appear to be based on the pure order of the search results, yet you assume other people's search habits are?

Comment: http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/study/2276184/no-1-position-in-google-gets-33-of-search-traffic-study

Answer (score 1):

Based on in-house data of online ad impressions, there is a [study](https://chitika.com/google-positioning-value) that deals with this topic. It shows that websites, which are listed on the first of Google's result pages for a specific search query, receive on average 32.5% of visitor traffic, whereas the second page only receives 17.6% with rapid decline for the following pages. Based on these figures, the first 5 SERPs receive a combined traffic of 75.7%.

If you take these figures as an estimate, it becomes clear that organic visibility of a website is very important in order to make it as easy as possible to be found. Users are also more likely to ignore advertising and focus on organic search results. A [study by GroupM UK and Nielsen](https://econsultancy.com/blog/10586-ppc-accounts-for-just-6-of-total-search-clicks-infographic) from 2012 based on 1.4 billion search queries suggests that organic search results receive 94% of clicks opposed to only 6% for paid clicks.

Although we cannot infer individual browsing behavior from theses numbers, there is a strong indication that users lose interest in search results that are not on the first 2 pages and a majority will ignore ad results.

Comment: +1 This conclusion has been a solid one for at least 10 years or more - people rarely go past the second page for search results and rarely prefer ads.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people just look the first, maybe the second, results' page and then if don't find what is looking for, refine the search terms and search again. But there is not an algorithm for that.